# Finding consecutive records

Tags: t-sql

I have followed code which is supposed to give me consecutive records using PlanId and costcentreid. for example in the image the record number 7 has costcentreid of 14 and the costcentreid before that is 5, so then it will ignore all the records before that and return me StartDate of 2017-07-12. if the previous record was of the same cost centre, then it would keep going back till the cost centre is different and then return me the lowest date but it's not doing that. i have provided my sql. Could you please help?

Sample Data:

Scenario 1: Correct Answer should be '2017-07-12 11:56:52.560'

```
   DECLARE @T TABLE (StartDate, PlanId, CostCentreId, PositionId, CostCentreFlavourID, CustomerPositionID)
INSERT @T(StartDate, PLanId, CostCentreID, PositionId, CostCentreFlavourID, CustomerPOsitionID)
VALUES('1998-10-23 00:00:00.000', 19130, 14, 129, 3, 1, 766 ),
('2010-06-22 00:00:00.000', 19130, 207, 25, 3, 1,16247),
('2012-05-01 16:27:04.460', 19130, 42, 14, 3, 1,23946),
('2013-04-30 18:57:57.617', 19130, 295, 14, 3, 1,29453),
('2015-03-03 09:31:28.133', 19130, 275, 5, 3,1, 39286),
('2015-06-26 15:48:35.637', 19130, 195, 5, 3,1,41985),
('2017-07-12 11:56:52.560', 19130, 1445, 14, 3, 1,57699)
```

Scenario 2: Correct Answer should be : '2015-06-26 15:48:35.637'

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (StartDate, PlanId, CostCentreId, PositionId, CostCentreFlavourID, CustomerPositionID)
INSERT @T(StartDate, PLanId, CostCentreID, PositionId, CostCentreFlavourID, CustomerPOsitionID)
VALUES('1998-10-23 00:00:00.000', 19130, 14, 129, 3,1,766 ),
('2010-06-22 00:00:00.000', 19130, 207, 25, 3, 1,16247),
('2012-05-01 16:27:04.460', 19130, 42, 14, 3, 1,23946),
('2013-04-30 18:57:57.617', 19130, 295, 14, 3, 1,29453),
('2015-03-03 09:31:28.133', 19130, 275, 5, 3, 1,39286),
('2015-06-26 15:48:35.637', 19130, 195, 14, 3,1, 41985),
('2017-07-12 11:56:52.560', 19130, 1445, 14, 3, 1,57699)
```

Scenario 3: Correct Answer should be: '2012-05-01 16:27:04.460'

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (StartDate, PlanId, CostCentreId, PositionId, CostCentreFlavourID, CustomerPositionID)
INSERT @T(StartDate, PLanId, CostCentreID, PositionId, CostCentreFlavourID, CustomerPOsitionID)
VALUES('1998-10-23 00:00:00.000', 19130, 14, 129, 3,1,766 ),
('2010-06-22 00:00:00.000', 19130, 207, 25, 3,1, 16247),
('2012-05-01 16:27:04.460', 19130, 42, 14, 3,1, 23946),
('2013-04-30 18:57:57.617', 19130, 295, 14, 3,1, 29453),
('2015-03-03 09:31:28.133', 19130, 275, 14, 3, 1,39286),
('2015-06-26 15:48:35.637', 19130, 195, 14, 3,1, 41985),
('2017-07-12 11:56:52.560', 19130, 1445, 14, 3,1, 57699)
```

[image]

```
WITH cte
AS (SELECT cp1.StartDate,
       fp.PlanId,
       p.CostCentreID,
       p.PositionID,
       fp.CostCentreFlavourId,
       fp.CustomerWithNDISNumberOfPlans,
       cp1.CustomerPositionID,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cp1.CustomerID ORDER BY cp1.StartDate) AS CustomerRow,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cp1.CustomerID, p.CostCentreID ORDER BY cp1.StartDate) AS CustomerCostCentreRow ,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cp1.CustomerID ORDER BY cp1.StartDate)
       - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cp1.CustomerID, p.CostCentreID ORDER BY cp1.StartDate) rn3
FROM #FlavouredPlans fp
    INNER JOIN dbo.tblCustomerPositions cp1
        ON cp1.CustomerID = fp.LADSCustomerID
    INNER JOIN dbo.tblPositions p
        ON p.PositionID = cp1.PositionID
    --AND fp.CostCentreId = p.CostCentreID
WHERE fp.CostCentreFlavourId = 3
      AND fp.OrderOfPlans = 1
       ),
 ctePositionStartDate
AS (SELECT *,
       MIN(cte.StartDate) OVER (PARTITION BY PlanId, CostCentreID, startdate, rn3) MinStartDate,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PlanId ORDER BY cte.StartDate ASC) [Order]
FROM cte )

SELECT *
FROM ctePositionStartDate
WHERE ctePositionStartDate.planid = 19130
```

Comment: Please don't post images for your sample data. The best way to post sample data is ddl+dml (create table and insert into statements). Also, please post desired results. It really helps people to get their answer correct.

Comment: I have provided ddl and dml statements. i will do some more editing to explain my question more. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can get your result by using window functions. Check this query

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (StartDate datetime, PlanId int, CostCentreId int, PositionId int, CostCentreFlavourID int, CustomerPositionID int)
INSERT @T(StartDate, PLanId, PositionId, CostCentreID, CostCentreFlavourID, CustomerPOsitionID)
VALUES
    ('19981023 00:00:00.000', 19130, 14, 129, 3,1),
    ('20100622 00:00:00.000', 19130, 207, 25, 3,1),
    ('20120501 16:27:04.460', 19130, 42, 14, 3,1),
    ('20130430 18:57:57.617', 19130, 295, 12, 3,1),
    ('20150303 09:31:28.133', 19130, 275, 14, 3, 1),
    ('20150626 15:48:35.637', 19130, 195, 14, 3,1),
    ('20170712 11:56:52.560', 19130, 1445, 14, 3,1)


select
    *
from (
    select
        *, row_number() over (partition by PlanId, CostCentreID, rn1 - rn2 order by StartDate) r3
        , max(StartDate) over (partition by PlanId, CostCentreID, rn1 - rn2) mx1
        , max(StartDate) over (partition by PlanId) mx2
    from (
        select 
            *, row_number()over(partition by PlanId order by StartDate) rn1
            , row_number()over(partition by PlanId, CostCentreID order by StartDate) rn2
        from 
            @T
    ) t
) t
where
    mx1 = mx2
    and r3 = 1
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What exactly does not work? Query passes all your scenarios. Give some examples when query returns wrong result